# Android textdata to google spreadsheet

Tags: java, android, google-docs

I would like to write android applications text data like name and watso ever data to the Spreadsheet that i have created in my acc. Is this posibble? If not how can i get the data from the textboxes to a Online server?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this :

- [Google Spreadsheet sample application code](http://code.google.com/p/google-spreadsheet-lib-android/downloads/detail?name=GSS_Client_Android.zip&can=2&q=) (zip)
- [Google Speadsheet lib](http://code.google.com/p/google-spreadsheet-lib-android/downloads/detail?name=gss-lib-2.2b1.zip&can=2&q=)

Note : this is not official Google stuff.

Comment: Yes thanks reno but please take note that i want other peoples entry to my spreadsheet this application simply shows my own acc spreadsheets, please help further thanks